# I am having trouble linstalling libc6:amd64 would break locales, and deconfiguration is not permitted

Tags: security, rtmpdump

I am having trouble Installing having libc6_2.23-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb using Ubuntu 12.04.5 Precise server.

It is giving this error; please see the screenshot is based on USN-3283-2.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.